# (NEXT.js) Problem in finding the module even if the path is correct with the official documentation of NEXT.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, web-development-server, web-frontend

I've recently started learning the next.js and I'm in chapter 4(Creating Layouts and Pages) of the official documentation of next.js .
in chapter 4 i'm asked to create a file name layout.tsx and paste this code

```
import React from 'react';
import SideNav from '@/app/ui/dashboard/sidenav';

export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
 return (
<div className="flex h-screen flex-col md:flex-row md:overflow-hidden">
  <div className="w-full flex-none md:w-64">
    <SideNav />
  </div>
  <div className="flex-grow p-6 md:overflow-y-auto md:p-12">{children}</div>
</div>
 );
 }
```

So, when i paste this code it says

```
"message": "Cannot find module '@/app/ui/dashboard/sidenav' or its corresponding type declarations.",
```

This is layout.tsx inside app/dashboard
[layout.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RtuI.png)

import directory that i copied from the documentation [directory of layout.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPp7a.png)

and this is sidenav.tsx which is in app/ui/dashboard which is the file i have to import is layout.tsx
[sidenav.tsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGHqo.png)

The directory goes like this [directory_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLzY7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are using TS here, and if you want to use `@` to prefix your path when importing, you have to configure your `tsconfig.json` in your project root and add a `path` inside your `compilerOptions` like below:

```json
{
 "compilerOptions": {
    "path": {
      "@/*": ["./app/**"] 
    }

 }
}
```

but simplest workaround is using a relative path `../app/ui/dashboard/sidenav`